# Different page content for default pages on Wordpress Multisite

Tags: multisite

I've got this code which sets up 4 default pages on every new site install on Wordpress MU. I was wondering how I could set up different 'post_content' for each of the four pages?

---

```
function default_pages( $blog_id )
{
$default_pages = array(
    'Contact',
    'Information',
    'About',
    'Home',
);

switch_to_blog( $blog_id );

if ( $current_pages = get_pages() )
    $default_pages = array_diff( $default_pages, wp_list_pluck( $current_pages, 'post_title' ) );

foreach ( $default_pages as $page_title ) {        
    $data = array(
        'post_title'   => $page_title,
        'post_content' => "This is your '$page_title' page. Enter in your content here.",
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_type'    => 'page',
    );

    wp_insert_post( add_magic_quotes( $data ) );
}

restore_current_blog();
}

add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'default_pages' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `$default_pages` array being associated array, where a key is page title and a value is page content. Then modify your foreach loop to fetch `$key => $value` pairs and use it for the `wp_insert_post` function. Like this:

```
function default_pages( $blog_id )
{
$default_pages = array(
    'Contact'     => "This is your 'Contact' page. Enter in your content here.",
    'Information' => "This is your 'Information' page. Enter in your content here.",
    'About'       => "This is your 'About' page. Enter in your content here.",
    'Home'        => "This is your 'Home' page. Enter in your content here.",
);

switch_to_blog( $blog_id );

if ( $current_pages = get_pages() )
    $default_pages = array_diff( $default_pages, wp_list_pluck( $current_pages, 'post_title' ) );

foreach ( $default_pages as $page_title => $page_content ) {        
    $data = array(
        'post_title'   => $page_title,
        'post_content' => $page_content,
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_type'    => 'page',
    );

    wp_insert_post( add_magic_quotes( $data ) );
}

restore_current_blog();
}

add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'default_pages' );
```